# SEO/Structured data: Tag whole page as review or only snippet

Tags: seo, google, structured-data, user-reviews

We write long reviews (+3000 words) on specific products (eg certain software), which also include a lot of general specifics etc etc.
What will be better for rankings / SEO:

1. tagging the whole page as "review"
2. tag the long informational content (including extensive review) as article of blogpost and only our review summary as review?
3. another option? which?

Comment: Are you planning to use json-ld, microdata, or rdf-a?

Comment: JSON-lD. We currently use microdata, but google seems to not understand everything as well as their testing tool does, that's why we are switching to JSON-LD.